# how to sort a @wire data array in JS

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I need help! According to this post (https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/11/content-delivery-api-to-extend-or-integrate-content.html)I managed to receive content from our CMS.

Now I would like to sort the received in the JS controller, I therefore created a contentNode "sortnumber".

This is the JS adapter - any ideas?

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from "lwc";
import initMethod from "@salesforce/apex/MCWrapperController.initMethod";
export default class tripItinerary extends LightningElement {
  @wire(initMethod) results;
  
  /* my custom function, will use it later */
  get jsonData() {
    console.log('results', this.results.data); //is working fine I get all the data
    // test 1: failed
    //const result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.results));
    //result.data.sort();
    // test 2: failed
    // const result = this.results.data;
    // result.sort(function (a, b) {
    //   return a.data.contentNodes.sortnumber.value - b.data.contentNodes.sortnumber.value;
    // });
    return this.results;
    }
}
```

The problem is, that I get no access to a sortable array!!

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: What does your data actually look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this I guess

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from "lwc";
import initMethod from "@salesforce/apex/MCWrapperController.initMethod";
export default class tripItinerary extends LightningElement {
  results
  @wire(initMethod)
  getResults(response) {
    const {data, error} = response;
    if (data) {
      // if your structure is different, to debug your actual data
      // console.log(data);
      this.results = [...data].sort((a, b) => a.data.contentNodes.sortnumber.value - b.data.contentNodes.sortnumber.value)
    } else if (error) {
      // handle error
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to shallow copy, but you don't need to deep copy (stringify/parse). You also don' need return if you don't use `{}`. It could be written `this.results = [...data].sort((a, b) => a.data.contentNodes.sortnumber.value - b.data.contentNodes.sortnumber.value);`

Comment: I added JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)) just for debugging purposes, but you're right, just after coming from `Apex` data is not yet wrapped into Proxy

Comment: regarding sort, just wanted to leave the code untouched if possible, so it's easier to understand. Don't think `[...data]` here is necessary (shallow copy) either

Comment: Array.sort modifies the original array, but won't be able to because the data will be wrapped in a read-only membrane. The read-only membrane protects the internal cache that could otherwise be corrupted. As such, the spread operator `[...value]` is necessary here.

Comment: many thanks for your support. although its not up and running jet, I'm sure, that's the right track. @ytiq could I use `results` in the 'html' and access all the fields then?

Comment: ok, coming closer: with the code from @ytiq - I now get the following error `[Cannot assign to read only property '0' of object '[object Array]']`. Does this relate to your comment @sfdcfox?

Comment: @Marco yep. You need to shallow copy the array.

Comment: updated, thanks fox. I always forget that in JS `sort` modifies array itself

Comment: @Marco updated the code with sfdcfox comment. Should be working now

Comment: @ytiq @sfdcfox - many thanks for your support - great input! I managed now to sort it by using `const resultOrdered = data
        .slice()
        .sort(
          (a, b) =>
            a.contentNodes.sortnumber.value -
            b.contentNodes.sortnumber.value
        );` hope, this is the best way to make a shallow copy. Have a great one!

Comment: @Maserick `someArray.slice()` and `[...someArray]` do the same thing.

Comment: thank you @sfdcfox